# how do i debug a java ant program, so that I understand the flow of the program?

Tags: java, debugging, ant

Hello I am new to Java and I have a question regarding java debugging so I recently got hold of a Java ant code that is very large so How do i debug to understnad the flow of the program. Usually I debug small codes but this time I dont know where it begins and where it ends. So what is the ideal way to understnad the flow of a java program.

Comment: You can for example use debugger in your IDE (such as Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You could use and Integrated Development Environment (IDE) like Eclipse or IntelliJ which have great support for debugging.

What do you exactly mean with "Java ant code" ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple put breakpoints just like a regular java program and run the server in debug mode or Run Java Application in Debug mode.

Ant is only a build tool.